# How to populate custom tables with rows of data

Tags: table

I'm trying to populate a custom table called countries, with two rows of data. The custom table is created when the plugin is activated. The rows need to be added when the plugin is activated. The code for the custom table is fine, & the custom table is created. My code so far:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'mp_insert_countries_rows' );
function mp_insert_countries_rows(){

global $wpdb;
$mp_insert_country = $wpdb->prefix . 'countries';

$insert_country_rows = $wpdb->insert(

$mp_insert_country,
array(
'id' => '1',
'name' => 'UK',
'labour_cost' => '20',
'overheads' => '0.45',
'profit' => '0.22'     
),

array(
'id' => '2',
'name' =>'China',
'labour_cost' => '6',
'overheads' => '0.27',
'profit' => '0.17'  
));  

 require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
 dbDelta(  $insert_country_rows );
}
```

How should I correct this? Thanks

Comment: If you set `WP_DEBUG` to true in wp-config.php file, what do you notice when you activate the plugin? Also are you really providing table structure for dbDelta function?

Comment: @sri The only message I get is on the plugin page, `The plugin generated 765 characters of unexpected output during activation. ` I don't get anything on the actual plugin  page . Thanks.

Comment: I think you are mixing things together. You use `dbDelta( $sql )`  to create the table and `$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );` to insert the data (more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows)). You don't take the output from `$wpdb->insert()` into `dbDelta()`. Check it out and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this article on WP.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) it seems you have to create your database first, with some SQL:

```
function mp_install_table() {
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "countries";

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name tinytext NOT NULL,
        labour_cost INT,
        overheads FLOAT,
        profits FLOAT
    );";

   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
   dbDelta( $sql );
}
```

And after you have your table you can add rows:

```
function mp_install_country_data() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "countries";

    $wpdb->insert(
        $table_name,
        array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'UK',
            'labour_cost' => '20',
            'overheads' => '0.45',
            'profits' => '0.22'     
        ),

        array(
            'id' => '2',
            'name' =>'China',
            'labour_cost' => '6',
            'overheads' => '0.27',
            'profits' => '0.17'  
        )
    );  
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: `Profits` also has an s on the end

Comment: I edited my answer.